# Python POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

I m using python requests to search the following site: https://www.investing.com/ for the terms "Durable Goods Orders US"

I check in the "Network" tab of the inspect panel, and it seems it is simply done with the following form: 'quotes_search_text':'Durable Goods Orders US'

So I tried with python:

```
URL = 'https://www.investing.com/'
data = {'quotes_search_text':'Durable Goods Orders US'}
resp = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
```

However this doesnt return the result that i can see while doing it manually.
All the search results should have "gs-title" as a class attribute (as per the page inspection) but when I do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
soup.select(".gs-title")
```

I see no results...
Is there some aspect of POST request that I am not taking into account? (im a complete noob here)

Comment: I believe your `find_all` selector is looking for a class attribute when it's expecting an HTML tag.

Comment: @double_j no i'm looking for a class attribute... here what the target element looks like: `<a class="gs-title" href="https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/durable-goods-orders-86" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/durable-goods-orders-86&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi28NG5tK7TAhWOa1AKHVhUBncQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;usg=AFQjCNEuRaJ1WI-VxrmeJ5VISPuraZ_Sug" data-ctorig="https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/durable-goods-orders-86">United States <b>Durable Goods Orders</b> MoM</a>`

Comment: That's okay, but BeautifulSoup will never find that tag the way you have it right now. You should write it like this: `soup.find_all('a', {'class':'gs-title'})`

Comment: If you want to use CSS selectors then you need to use the [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method.

Comment: @double_jThe correct syntax doesn't return anything either... I'll edit my question with it though. In fact I have been printing `resp.text` to manually search with ctrl-f in it, and I could see the correct page is not returned. So it's really with request that i need help.

Comment: Okay the next issue is it does a POST to this URL: [https://www.investing.com/search/service/search](https://www.investing.com/search/service/search) Not the one you have listed.

Comment: @double_j So does that mean I need to modified my `URL` variable? And how did you figured that out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141995/discussion-between-double-j-and-jim-basquiat).

Comment: @double_j Do you see the chat? I sent you a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going over this in detail in the chat, there are many changes. In order to retrieve the information your looking for, you need to run the JS that's being run on their end. You can change the `query` variable to whatever you want.

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element'

query = 'Durable Goods Orders US'
query_formatted = quote_plus(query)

data = {
    'key':'AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1gunmMikTzQqY',
    'num':10,
    'hl':'en',
    'prettyPrint':'true',
    'source':'gcsc',
    'gss':'.com',
    'cx':'015447872197439536574:fy9sb1kxnp8',
    'q':query_formatted,
    'googlehost':'www.google.com'
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Referer':'https://www.investing.com/search?q=' + query_formatted,
}
resp = requests.get(URL, params=data, headers=headers)

j = json.loads(resp.text)
# print(resp.text)
for r in j['results']:
    print(r['title'], r['url'])
```